# python exception : parse error

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, exception

am trying to write an exception while parsing a link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

IDFile = open('IDs.csv')
IDReader = csv.reader(IDFile)
ID = list(IDReader)
for row in ID:
    col1,col2 = row
    ID ="%s" % (col2)

    url = requests.get("http://.......")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "lxml")
    print(soup)
    ## execute more code if "results:" is greater than zero
```

The output of "print(soup)" is:

```
<html><body><p>{ success:true ,results:0,rows:[], ID:5432}</p></body></html>
```

The IDs.csv contains:

```
14-Aug-2015,5431
30-May-2015,5432
17-Feb-2015,5433
```

I want to write an exception where:

if output of "print(soup) has "results:0", then APPEND the variable ID (5432 in this case) to zero-results.txt file and process the next id (5433) from my ids.csv
file.

else if output of "print(soup) has "result:1" or greater, then continue to process the remaining code

Please help, thanx

Comment: There are some problems with your question. What does it have to do with exceptions? Which part do you need help with? Are you wondering how to extract `results:0` and `ID:5432`? Do you want to know how to append to a file? These are separate issues that belong in separate questions.

Comment: You need to parse JSON, analyse it, act accordingly, well just write the program.

Comment: @alex-hall, am a noob so i may be technically wrong using the term 'exception'. But yes, i do want to know how to extract the value of "results"

Comment: @Andrey Ironically that's valid JS syntax for an object but it's not JSON because there aren't quotes. Some searching tells me that [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/), [RSON](https://code.google.com/p/rson/) and YAML may be suitable for parsing this. However if their use case is simple enough regexes will suffice.

Comment: @andrey am just learning to parse, so any help to parse the value of "results:" will really help learn. thank you

Comment: @zs_python this looks like JSON. 1) Extract contents of that <p> element 2) use python JSON module to parse it 3) extract  results

Comment: If you are getting a parse error exception as the title suggests, then please post the entire exception message.

Comment: @Andrey again, that is NOT JSON. JSON requires that the keys be enclosed in double quotes. `json.loads("{ success:true ,results:0,rows:[], ID:5432}")` fails.

Comment: @AlexHall it is json in practice, just not well formed, you can parse it this away http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931454/how-to-parse-somewhat-wrong-json-with-python

Comment: Yes, I saw that question after some searching which led me to suggest YAML an hour ago. It doesn't make sense to say " it is json in practice, just not well formed". It simply isn't JSON. In particular I was pointing out that your suggestion "2) use python JSON module to parse it" wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to grab the result number:

```
import re
content = str(soup)
matchObj = re.search("results:(\\d)", content)
resultNum = int(matchObj.group(1))
if resultNum > 0:
    # do stuff
    pass
else:
    # do stuff
    pass
```

To grab the ID, again use the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module, or use one of the soup methods.

I think your question is asking about [if statements](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).  Exceptions are part of error handling, which is a different topic.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much. Really appreciate your effort to help :)