# Finding highest value from pandas column containing dictionaries

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a file with data as follows:

```
 NAME,    FOOD
"John", {"Apple":10, "Banana":10,  "Mango":5}
"Jack", {"Apple":5, "Mango":10}
"Jill", {"Apple:7, "Banana":15}
```

I want to find the highest value of each key contained in the column named food. For example, I want to print (or store it as a variable) something like follows:
 John eats most of the Apples, which is 10.
 Jill eats most of the Bananas, which is 15.
 Jack eats most of the Mango, which is 10.

I am aware of iterrows() or itertuples(), but I could not proceed after iterating over the rows. Is there any good method to follow when dealing with such data of >10000 rows?

Comment: Is this file a raw csv file? you may not even need to use a dataframe just for this purpose.

Comment: Yes. That is a raw csv file.

Comment: So the raw csv literally has braces in it?

Comment: Yes. Because it was created from some other python script.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is main problem read `csv` to `DataFrame`, for parsing I use [yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1931531/2901002):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import yaml, csv

temp=u""""NAME,    FOOD
John", {"Apple":10, "Banana":10,  "Mango":5}
"Jack", {"Apple":5, "Mango":10}
"Jill", {"Apple":7, "Banana":15}"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 header=None, 
                 sep='{', 
                 quoting =csv.QUOTE_NONE, 
                 skiprows=1, 
                 names=['a','b'])

df['b'] = ('{' + df['b']).apply(yaml.load)
df['a'] = df['a'].str.strip(', "')
print (df)    
      a                                        b
0  John  {'Apple': 10, 'Mango': 5, 'Banana': 10}
1  Jack                {'Apple': 5, 'Mango': 10}
2  Jill               {'Apple': 7, 'Banana': 15}

print (type(df.loc[0,'b']))
<class 'dict'>
```

Then create new `DataFrame` by constructor and get [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) values per rows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['b'].values.tolist())
df['b'] = df1.idxmax(1)
df['c'] = df1.max(1).astype(int)
print (df)
      a       b   c
0  John   Apple  10
1  Jack   Mango  10
2  Jill  Banana  15
```

EDIT:

Maybe also works `json` parser:

```
import json, csv

temp=u""""NAME,    FOOD
John", {"Apple":10, "Banana":10,  "Mango":5}
"Jack", {"Apple":5, "Mango":10}
"Jill", {"Apple":7, "Banana":15}"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), 
                 header=None, 
                 sep='{', 
                 quoting =csv.QUOTE_NONE, 
                 skiprows=1, 
                 names=['a','b'])

df['b'] = ('{' + df['b']).apply(json.loads)
df['a'] = df['a'].str.strip(', "')
print (df) 
      a                                        b
0  John  {'Mango': 5, 'Apple': 10, 'Banana': 10}
1  Jack                {'Mango': 10, 'Apple': 5}
2  Jill               {'Apple': 7, 'Banana': 15}

print (type(df.loc[0,'b']))
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `df` before assigning to the `df.FOOD` attribute?

Comment: @not_a_robot - Thanks, you are right. So I have to rebuild solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the chance to run this on your actual file, so you'll have to deal with reading dictionaries that are stored as string in your file into actual dictionaries (perhaps use something like `eval`), but this ought to work:

```
data = {}

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        if idx > 0:
            name, line_data = line.split(',')
            data[name] = eval(line_data)

for k, v in data.items():
    top = max(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    print('%s eats the most of %s (n = %d)' % (k, top[0], int(top[1]))
```