# Convert json like structure into json in python language

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, key-value

I am calling 3rd party API which is sending response in text/html format. It is a key value pair but not exactly json.

current : `{ data:"true" ,results:15}`
expected : `"data":"true" , "results":15}`

I am trying to parse using `json.loads` to create a dictionary but as it's clear from the structure it's not exactly json and python throws the error as well.

> {JSONDecodeError}Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Is there a way to fix the response and convert it into proper json or is there any other way where I can get key value pair out of the response

yaml is unable to help me in this case coz, entire data:

```
{ success:true ,results:9,rows:[{sym:"FEDERALBNK",ser:"EQ",Ind:"-",face:"2",sub:"Annual General Meeting And Dividend Rs.5/- Per Share",exDt:"02-Sep-2010",recordDt:"-",bcStartDt:"04-Sep-2010",bcEndDt:"13-Sep-2010",ndStartDt:"-",comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited",isin:"INE171A01011",ndEndDt:"-"},{sym:"FEDERALBNK",ser:"EQ",Ind:"-",face:"2",sub:"Annual General Meeting And Dividend Rs.8.50 Per Share",exDt:"23-Aug-2011",recordDt:"-",bcStartDt:"25-Aug-2011",bcEndDt:"03-Sep-2011",ndStartDt:"-",comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited",isin:"INE171A01011",ndEndDt:"-"},{sym:"FEDERALBNK",ser:"EQ",Ind:"-",face:"2",sub:"Annual General Meeting And Dividend Rs.9/- Per Share",exDt:"20-Jul-2012",recordDt:"-",bcStartDt:"24-Jul-2012",bcEndDt:"02-Aug-2012",ndStartDt:"-",comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited",isin:"INE171A01011",ndEndDt:"-"},{sym:"FEDERALBNK",ser:"EQ",Ind:"-",face:"2",sub:"Annual General Meeting/Dividend Rs 9/- Per Share",exDt:"09-Jul-2013",recordDt:"-",bcStartDt:"11-Jul-2013",bcEndDt:"20-Jul-2013",ndStartDt:"-",comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited",isin:"INE171A01011",ndEndDt:"-"},{sym:"FEDERALBNK",ser:"EQ",Ind:"-",face:"2",sub:"Annual General Meeting / Dividend - Rs 2/- Per Share",exDt:"04-Jul-2014",recordDt:"-",bcStartDt:"08-Jul-2014",bcEndDt:"17-Jul-2014",ndStartDt:"-",comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited",isin:"INE171A01011",ndEndDt:"-"},{sym:"FEDERALBNK",ser:"EQ",Ind:"-",face:"2",sub:"Annual General Meeting / Dividend - Rs 2.20/- Per Share",exDt:"28-May-2015",recordDt:"-",bcStartDt:"01-Jun-2015",bcEndDt:"05-Jun-2015",ndStartDt:"-",comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited",isin:"INE171A01011",ndEndDt:"-"},{sym:"FEDERALBNK",ser:"EQ",Ind:"-",face:"2",sub:" Annual General Meeting/ Dividend -Re 0.70 Per Share",exDt:"29-Jul-2016",recordDt:"-",bcStartDt:"02-Aug-2016",bcEndDt:"11-Aug-2016",ndStartDt:"-",comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited",isin:"INE171A01011",ndEndDt:"-"},{sym:"FEDERALBNK",ser:"EQ",Ind:"-",face:"2",sub:" Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Re 0.90 Per Share",exDt:"03-Jul-2017",recordDt:"-",bcStartDt:"05-Jul-2017",bcEndDt:"14-Jul-2017",ndStartDt:"-",comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited",isin:"INE171A01011",ndEndDt:"-"},{sym:"FEDERALBNK",ser:"EQ",Ind:"-",face:"2",sub:" Annual General Meeting/Dividend- Re 1 Per Share",exDt:"02-Aug-2018",recordDt:"-",bcStartDt:"04-Aug-2018",bcEndDt:"10-Aug-2018",ndStartDt:"-",comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited",isin:"INE171A01011",ndEndDt:"-"}]}
```

after using yaml it turns into:

```
{'success:true': None, 'results:9': None, 'rows': [{'sym:"FEDERALBNK"': None, 'ser:"EQ"': None, 'Ind:"-"': None, 'face:"2"': None, 'sub:"Annual General Meeting And Dividend Rs.5/- Per Share"': None, 'exDt:"02-Sep-2010"': None, 'recordDt:"-"': None, 'bcStartDt:"04-Sep-2010"': None, 'bcEndDt:"13-Sep-2010"': None, 'ndStartDt:"-"': None, 'comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited"': None, 'isin:"INE171A01011"': None, 'ndEndDt:"-"': None}, {'sym:"FEDERALBNK"': None, 'ser:"EQ"': None, 'Ind:"-"': None, 'face:"2"': None, 'sub:"Annual General Meeting And Dividend Rs.8.50 Per Share"': None, 'exDt:"23-Aug-2011"': None, 'recordDt:"-"': None, 'bcStartDt:"25-Aug-2011"': None, 'bcEndDt:"03-Sep-2011"': None, 'ndStartDt:"-"': None, 'comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited"': None, 'isin:"INE171A01011"': None, 'ndEndDt:"-"': None}, {'sym:"FEDERALBNK"': None, 'ser:"EQ"': None, 'Ind:"-"': None, 'face:"2"': None, 'sub:"Annual General Meeting And Dividend Rs.9/- Per Share"': None, 'exDt:"20-Jul-2012"': None, 'recordDt:"-"': None, 'bcStartDt:"24-Jul-2012"': None, 'bcEndDt:"02-Aug-2012"': None, 'ndStartDt:"-"': None, 'comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited"': None, 'isin:"INE171A01011"': None, 'ndEndDt:"-"': None}, {'sym:"FEDERALBNK"': None, 'ser:"EQ"': None, 'Ind:"-"': None, 'face:"2"': None, 'sub:"Annual General Meeting/Dividend Rs 9/- Per Share"': None, 'exDt:"09-Jul-2013"': None, 'recordDt:"-"': None, 'bcStartDt:"11-Jul-2013"': None, 'bcEndDt:"20-Jul-2013"': None, 'ndStartDt:"-"': None, 'comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited"': None, 'isin:"INE171A01011"': None, 'ndEndDt:"-"': None}, {'sym:"FEDERALBNK"': None, 'ser:"EQ"': None, 'Ind:"-"': None, 'face:"2"': None, 'sub:"Annual General Meeting / Dividend - Rs 2/- Per Share"': None, 'exDt:"04-Jul-2014"': None, 'recordDt:"-"': None, 'bcStartDt:"08-Jul-2014"': None, 'bcEndDt:"17-Jul-2014"': None, 'ndStartDt:"-"': None, 'comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited"': None, 'isin:"INE171A01011"': None, 'ndEndDt:"-"': None}, {'sym:"FEDERALBNK"': None, 'ser:"EQ"': None, 'Ind:"-"': None, 'face:"2"': None, 'sub:"Annual General Meeting / Dividend - Rs 2.20/- Per Share"': None, 'exDt:"28-May-2015"': None, 'recordDt:"-"': None, 'bcStartDt:"01-Jun-2015"': None, 'bcEndDt:"05-Jun-2015"': None, 'ndStartDt:"-"': None, 'comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited"': None, 'isin:"INE171A01011"': None, 'ndEndDt:"-"': None}, {'sym:"FEDERALBNK"': None, 'ser:"EQ"': None, 'Ind:"-"': None, 'face:"2"': None, 'sub:" Annual General Meeting/ Dividend -Re 0.70 Per Share"': None, 'exDt:"29-Jul-2016"': None, 'recordDt:"-"': None, 'bcStartDt:"02-Aug-2016"': None, 'bcEndDt:"11-Aug-2016"': None, 'ndStartDt:"-"': None, 'comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited"': None, 'isin:"INE171A01011"': None, 'ndEndDt:"-"': None}, {'sym:"FEDERALBNK"': None, 'ser:"EQ"': None, 'Ind:"-"': None, 'face:"2"': None, 'sub:" Annual General Meeting/Dividend - Re 0.90 Per Share"': None, 'exDt:"03-Jul-2017"': None, 'recordDt:"-"': None, 'bcStartDt:"05-Jul-2017"': None, 'bcEndDt:"14-Jul-2017"': None, 'ndStartDt:"-"': None, 'comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited"': None, 'isin:"INE171A01011"': None, 'ndEndDt:"-"': None}, {'sym:"FEDERALBNK"': None, 'ser:"EQ"': None, 'Ind:"-"': None, 'face:"2"': None, 'sub:" Annual General Meeting/Dividend- Re 1 Per Share"': None, 'exDt:"02-Aug-2018"': None, 'recordDt:"-"': None, 'bcStartDt:"04-Aug-2018"': None, 'bcEndDt:"10-Aug-2018"': None, 'ndStartDt:"-"': None, 'comp:"The Federal Bank  Limited"': None, 'isin:"INE171A01011"': None, 'ndEndDt:"-"': None}]}
```

which i can't access like:

```
yaml.load(corporate_action)['rows'][0]['sym']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse somewhat wrong JSON with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931454/how-to-parse-somewhat-wrong-json-with-python)

Comment: @fluxens have added the entire json like structure which I was unable to parse using yaml. so it was not the solution for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex might help here. You can use `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re
import json


data = '{ data:"true" ,results:15}'
data = json.loads(re.sub(r"(\w+):", r'"\1":', data))
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{u'data': u'true', u'results': 15}
```

Comment: I have slightly optimised your solution to suit me. `re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z]+):", r'"\1":', data)` (\w+) was changing colon occurring in value side as well